# how to validate with valid Date object using javascript in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

I went through lot of articles to validate date format, but in my below code I am getting valid dates when I am passing string 'STARBUCKS STORE 18980'.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), an invalid date should be returned. My date validation function is breaking due to this.

```js
console.log(Date.parse('STARBUCKS STORE 18980')); //should return NaN
console.log(new Date('STARBUCKS STORE 18980')); // should return Invalid Date
```

Comment: @RoguSmith it *isn't* and the question is asking how to make the validation not say it is.

Comment: Interesting, I just checked the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). There is an example `new Date('foo-bar 2014')` which should return `Invalid Date`, but does actually return a date (in my Chrome console).

Comment: [Seems that everything is working](https://jsbin.com/woqenofanu/1/edit?js,console) - when exactly do you get a result that says the input is valid? EDIT: ah, it seems it works correctly in Firefox, but in Chrome it does produce some sort of date.

Comment: I have a function !!Date.parse('STARBUCKS STORE 18980') which is returning true

Comment: @VLAZ I can confirm that it works like expected in Firefox, but does not work in Chrome.

Comment: From the docs you link to: `There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated).`

Comment: In 'Fall-back to implementation-specific date formats' from link you provided, we can read `However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as simplified ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided,`